# Can't access public RDS on AWS even with public access

Tags: android, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to use an AWS RDS instance runnnig MySQL to store data from my Android application. How ever there is a problem when trying to connect to the database. Firstly I used MySQL workbench and the connection worked fine. When I tried the next day it doesn't work. Workbench cannot create a connection to the database. I double checked from the AWS console and everything seems fine on that end as well. How can I access this database now?

Comment: Did you tried accessing it from same network as yesterday? Is your firewall allows access? How did you open this "public" access - from any IP, IP range or something else?

Comment: I am using the same network as yesterday. And I dont think my firewall is interfering here. I switched on the open for public parameter to open for public. Is there anything else that needs to be done to open public access?

Comment: Check instance status, and verify in security group that you've opened server to the world.

Comment: *"it doesn't work."*  Please provide the exact, word-for-word error message.

Comment: @nevsv checked the security groups after you said. That was the problem! Thanks a load!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer! Apparently the problem was with the security groups. Updated the security groups to accept connections from TCP port 0-65535 from any IP and now the problem is solved!

Answer (score 3):

Even though newly created Amazon RDS instance is set to be "publicly available" it **does NOT** accept tcp traffic.

You need to create a new security group like this:

[image: create a security group]

And later on go to: **Instances-> "Your Instance" -> Modify -> Network & Security**

[image]

Comment: This was the answer I needed

Comment: Worked at first attempt!! Thank you so much!!